# Estimote iBeacon: Monitoring in background (Android)

Tags: android, background, ibeacon, estimote

I would like to have push notifications when my app is open but is in background. For now I have changed the Estimote Demo, and my app gives me a notification when my app is in foreground which is not much of use.
I post here my code of NotifyDemoActivity class which is called as soon as I open the app

```
public class NotifyDemoActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String TAG = NotifyDemoActivity.class.getSimpleName();
  private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 123;
  private BeaconManager beaconManager;
  private NotificationManager notificationManager;
  private Region region;
  private long[] mVibratePattern = { 0, 200, 200, 300 };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notify_demo);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    beacon.getMinor());
    region = new Region("rid", null, null, null);
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);

    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1), 0);

    beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new MonitoringListener() {
      @Override
      public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
        postNotification("Entered region");
      }

      @Override
      public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {
        postNotification("Exited region");
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
      finish();
      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onServiceReady() {
        try {
          beaconManager.startMonitoring(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Error while starting monitoring");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    beaconManager.disconnect();
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  private void postNotification(String msg) {
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(NotifyDemoActivity.this, NotifyDemoActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(
      NotifyDemoActivity.this,
      0,
      new Intent[]{notifyIntent},
      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(NotifyDemoActivity.this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beacon_gray)
    .setContentTitle("Notify Demo")
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setVibrate(mVibratePattern)
    .build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    TextView statusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    statusTextView.setText(msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Info from the Estimote site :


iOS 7 iBeacon Works Even When the App is Closed

This week Apple has rolled out a stable release of iOS 7.1. The new version brought all the people working with Beacons some pretty exciting changes. Namely: the app does not have to keep running in the background anymore to be able to send notifications to the user.

See more info on estimote community forum.

Comment: @ayasha Can you please join me [Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era) , I need some guidance on Estimote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should hold `BeaconManager` in your application class not in the activity.

Activity will be stopped, destroyed and `BeaconManager` will stop monitoring. Application on the other hand will still hold reference and will continue to monitor.

When a beacon is being found while monitoring your application class can post a notification. It trigger some activity when user decides to tap on it.

Comment: Thanks! It works now! ..I have a new problem related to Ranging/Monitoring now however :) Do you know how to do that each time the user enters in a new region gets a notification? That is if my blue beacon is closer I want to have a certain notification, but then if the green beacon gets closer I would like to have another one. I don't understand if this should be inside Monitoring or Ranging, I think Ranging but I don't understand where..

Comment: Monitoring is good choice here. Just find beacons' identifiers and start monitoring for three regions that corresponds yours three beacons.

Comment: what is the application class ur referring to? right now all my java files in the source folder as activity files

Comment: i had use the function in my code where beacon founds i call this function but it stops at beaconmanager.setMonitoringListener line and exited from this function.

Answer (score 0):

You should create service.

In your code you should do some changes.

After

> beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);

you should start "beacon service"

```
      if (!beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
          stopSelf();
      }

          beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
              @Override
              public void onServiceReady() {
                try {
                  beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                  Log.e("error", "Cannot start ranging", e);
                }
              }
          });
```

Also check if Bluetooth is active on you device.

In procedure beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new MonitoringListener() add commands to  create Notifications.